# RDP connection on Windows 10 Home / Education

Tags: windows-10, remote-desktop

We need to make an RDP connection from 2 computers (1 with Windows 10 Home, and 1 with Windows 10 Education) to a Windows Server 2016.

The problem is that I can't find RDP on the Windows 10 computers. How do I enable this utility?

Comment: _From_ both computers? What's the computer that you're connecting _to_?

Comment: Why not just try it ?

Comment: Windows 10 `home` don't have RDP/mstsc app. You can absolutely use something like mobaxterm for that. You'll also have to use different accounts, if you want them both to work simultaniously. Did you had a problem achieving that, or do you just ask if that's possible?

Comment: The windows 10 home and windows 10 Educartion will be RDP Client. will be connect to windows server 2016. The problem is that i can't find RD on Windows home and Education.

Comment: what happens when you run `mstsc` from the runbar, or a command prompt?

Comment: @FrankThomas MESSAGE : "IS NOT RECOGNIZED AS AN INTERNAL OR EXTERNAL COMMAND'

Comment: If you're only looking for an RDP client, you could just install the "Remote Desktop Connection" app from the Microsoft Store. AFAIK there should already be a Remote Desktop client app installed by default on Windows 10 Home and Windows 10 Education.